# How to display 2 times a row info from a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

Im trying to do a shopping cart using php, if the user click "add" it adds the product ID into a session array. Sometimes the array has the same ID 2 times or 3. 
My question is why when I run the query it only display the information 1 time and not 2.

Ex:

```
Array = $_SESSION['productsArray']
```

contains `(34, 43, 34)`

Each number is a product ID, my query only display '34' 1 time not 2

```
$ids = $_SESSION['productsArray']; 
$ids = join("','", $ids);   
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE pID IN ('$ids') ORDER BY pID";
$query_params = array(":ids" => $ids);

try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    die ('Failed to run query: ' . $ex->getMessage());
}

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($rows as $row):
    echo htmlentities($row['pName'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
endforeach;
```

Comment: Your `products` table has just one record for each `product_id`. So the query you are doing logically sends back 2 lines (regarding your example).

What are you planning to do with your results? Just show the pName?

Comment: You have no `:ids` in `$query`, what is that supposed to do in `$query_params`?

Comment: check my edited answer. You can use the code without modifying your session array now thanks to Barmar's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is only one record in the database.

Try using associative array with the id as key and the quantity as value like this without modifying your array in the session:

```
$ids =  array_count_values($_SESSION['products_array']); // now $ids = array("34"=>"2", "43"=>"1")
$query_params = array(":ids" => array_keys($ids));
```

And then to output the result do like this:

```
foreach ($rows as $row):
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $ids[$row['pID']]; $i++) {
    echo htmlentities($row['pName'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
}
endforeach;
```

We used the array_keys function to get the ids only to retrieve your data and and get the quantity from the session associative array and use the pID from each row to get the quantity and loop according to it.

Comment: Use `array_count_values($_SESSION['products_array'])` to get your `$ids` array.

Comment: Brilliant! sorry I didn't understand it but now i get it. I will edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
WHERE pID in (34, 43, 34)
```

it simply tests each row to see if it satisfies that condition. Even though the condition has `34` twice, there's only one row in the table that matches it, so the query only returns that one row.

If you want to get the row twice in your result, you need to do a separate query for each ID. You can combine them with `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE pID = 34
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM products WHERE pID = 43
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM products WHERE pID = 34
```

Comment: Hello Barmar, check my answer please and help improve it.I use only one query (his original one)